# Converting CSV to XLSX using openpyxl, but quote comes infront of numbers

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl

I tried to convert CSV to xlsx using openpyxl. The conversion was successful but i noticed quote (') in-front of numbers. Making it string instead of numbers. As I am new to python you help would be grateful.

Here is code I am using:

```
import os
import glob
import csv
import openpyxl

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader, start = 1):
            for c, val in enumerate(row, start = 1):
                ws.cell(row = r, column = c).value = val
    wb.save(csvfile + '.xlsx')
```

Comment: Most likely, you have quote characters in your data. If they are not supposed to be there, then the CSV is malformed. If the CSV was not created/saved using Excel (for example, if it was generated using a home-grown custom program) then you might be able to adjust the dialect of CSV in the call to `csv.reader()`. If you don't understand what I'm talking about, then edit your question to include some of the raw data from one of your CSV files. By "raw" I mean as if you opened it in Notepad and not Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with CSV files is that contain no data-typing so everything is a string. openpyxl does offer a "guess_types" mode that you can try and use but I strongly advise that you do the type conversion yourself based on your knowledge of the file, e.g. convert columns 3 and 4 to integers and 6 to floats.

FWIW you don't really need `for c, val in enumerate(row, start=1)` you can probably just do `ws.append(row)`

Comment: Some example over the example master?. I have same problem.

Comment: @Alexd2 I don"t understand what you mean.